# Exclude code in UISpec

Tags: iphone, testing, bdd, uispec

I am integrating FlurryAPI with my app, and I don't want it to start a link when I'm running my tests. However, since it's in the AppDelegate, I suppose it runs whenever I start the application for Acceptance Testing. I'm using UISpec, and I was wondering:

Is there any way to exclude code from running in UISpec, but still running in normal target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with UISpec but if you have 2 different targets and you want to include code in one but not the other, that is easy to do.

```
#ifndef UISPEC
(code to run in any target except UISpec target)
#endif
```

Then just add `-DUISPEC` to *Other C Flags* in UISpec target build settings.